# LibGDX program not responding with black screen

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a game with LibGDX, and am having some problems with a certain class (WorldGen.java). Every time I try to run the code normally, I get a black screen that says it is Not Responding when clicked, and there appear to be no errors. The program runs fine when any references to the methods in WorldGen.java are commented out. This seemed to work fine previously, and I have only changed the if statement in this class since then.

This code is intended to create an array of Strings, convert that to a List, and then print that to a txt file.

```java
package com.mygdx.rpg;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WorldGen {

    static List<String> printString = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
    static String mapData;
    static Path mapSavePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\"+username+"\\Desktop\\MapFile.txt");

    static Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    static String[] map = new String[1000000]; //right = +1, down = +100

    //problem with generate class, causes black screen and Not Responding to occur
    public static void generate(){
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){ //1000 x 1000 tiles, encompasses ALL world generation
            if(i>-1 && i<1001 || i>999000 && i<1000001){
                map[i]="-"; //void (top/bottom edges, must add to all tiles bordering edges of map)
            }else if(i%1000==0){
                map[i]="-"; //adds void to multiples of 1000 & 999+multiples of 1000 (left/right edges)
                map[i-1]="-";
            }else{
                map[i]="G"; //grass
            }
            mapData = Arrays.toString(map);
            mapData = mapData.replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","").replaceAll(",","");
            printString.add(mapData);
        }
    }

    public static void writeToFile(){
        try{
            Files.write(mapSavePath,printString,utf8);
        }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: Doing `mapData = Arrays.toString(map);` then `printString.add(mapData);` a million times for a Array of a millions Strings sounds very expensive.

Comment: This is just a large operation that will lock up your application until it completes (or runs out of memory), you need to move the work to another thread if you want to prevent the lockup. But more importantly, you have a performance issue, does this method all need to be run at the same time? The way many other games manage this or solve this issue is to only generate the necessary parts of the world as required, and never to store the whole world in memory, but to save it to a file, and load/unload parts as necessary.

Comment: Even moving this processing out of your loop may do what you want it to.

Comment: Just realized that was the problem. Thanks! Also, this is only run to generate the world for the first time, and I already have a system set up to only render the part of the world shown on the screen at a time.